# Selecting features of layer present just in one feature of another layer?

Tags: qgis, intersection, overlay

I'm a student approaching to QGIS 2.0.1-Dufour. My goal is to know how many features of a layer are present just in one feature of another layer. I tried both with the tools "spatial query" and "intersect" (see the picture) but I can't select just one feature.

How do I select the number of the red dots that are present in just one area defined by the black line?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to know is the number of the red dots that are present in just one area defined by the black line.

Vector | Analysis Tools | Points in Polygon will count the number of points for each polygon.

Since your "dots" are indeed lines - as the icon in the layer list indicates - try using Vector | Analysis Tools | Sum Line Lenght. It adds to columns: one total length, and one line count.

Comment: The drop-down menu of the input point vector layer doesn't give any option...

Comment: Could it be that your "dots" are lines?

Comment: Yes they're lines! Sorry